# PHP can't get post data from jQuery dynamic method

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I use `.after` method in Jquery to insert the html element.

This is my Jquery Code

```js
$('#add_terms').click(function () {
  var i = $('#terms>textarea').length;
  $terms = $('#terms' + i);
  i++;
  console.log($terms);
  $terms.after('<br><br>' + i + '.    <textarea id="terms' + i + '" name="terms[]" ' + 'cols="60" rows="2" style="vertical-align:middle;"></textarea>');
})
```

My html:

```html
 <table width="98%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" style="border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:0px 10px;">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1" action='' target="_self">
<tr>
  <td align="center"> terms</td>
  <td id="terms">
    1.
    <textarea id="terms1" name="terms[]" cols="60" rows="2"
      style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $terms1?></textarea>
    <br><br>
    2.
    <textarea id="terms2" name="terms[]" cols="60" rows="2"
      style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $terms2?></textarea>
    <br>

    <input id="add_terms" name="add_terms" type="button" class="bt-add" value="add" style="margin-top:10px">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input id="add" name="add" type="submit">
<input id="clear" name="clear" type="reset"  class="bt-return">
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

I post the form,then I can get the value of terms1 and terms2 with using

> print_r($_POST['terms']);

However, I can't get the value of `terms3`, `terms4`.

Comment: I am not actually seening any form of sending POST requests anywhere in this code. So my best guess, data does not get posted at all. There should be a form submit or an AJAX request somewhere there, which sends a POST request with the desired data

Comment: Is your inputs inside the `<form>` tag?

Comment: To reduce in length,I didn't post in my question.
I have edited.

Comment: You capture the button click event, but form still does not get submitted. `$('#add_terms').click(function(){` at the wery least must have a `$('#form1').submit()` right after `$terms.after(...);` otherwise the form won't be submitted at all.

Comment: You need to stop creating invalid nesting in your HTML, otherwise the error correction of the browser is likely to create a DOM from this, that is very different from what you expected. You can not nest `form` into a table like that - it either has to go around the complete `table` element, or be contained in a single table cell, `td`.

Comment: How are you submitting form? Using ajax or using $('#form1').submit() ?

Comment: Thx everyone.I have found the point.I put my `form` tag outside the `table` tag.Then it works

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin 
,Jon
,misorude
Sorry I'didn't type these element in my code.
Because I want to Simplify the problem.
I have edited the compelete code.

Comment: @MohammedBilal
Sorry for my unclear question.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this help you.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1" action='' target="_self">
  <td align="center"> terms</td>
  <td id="terms">
    1.
    <textarea id="terms1" name="terms[]" cols="60" rows="2"
      style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $terms1?></textarea>
    <br><br>
    2.
    <textarea id="terms2" name="terms[]" cols="60" rows="2"
      style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $terms2?></textarea>
    <br>

    <input id="add_terms" name="add_terms" type="submit" class="bt-add" value="add" style="margin-top:10px">
  </td>
</form>
```

Comment: with the add button user is just trying to adding a new textarea dynamically not submitting the form.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what have you changed, and why?

Comment: @Nico Haase thank you reply.  changed input type="button" to type="submit"

Comment: Please add all explanation to the answer itself by editing it, this should also contain a reason for your change

Comment: I have already checked, I don't know why this but actually jquery is written on that button to add more field.

Comment: Thx for your answer.I have found the point.I put my form tag outside the table tag.Then it works